# WP or function adding extra br tag

Tags: wordpress

I have this function added to functions.php  It allows me to use shortcodes for div tags. [div class =""] [/div]  when I place two of them together it or wordpress is adding an extra br tag.  Is there any way to prevent that?  here's the function:

```
function div_html($atts, $content = null) {

extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'class' => '',
), $atts ) );

$class = $class ? " class=\"$class\"" : NULL;

return "<div$class>$content</div>";
}
add_shortcode('div', 'div_html');
```

Comment: Are the shortcodes being places directly next to one another or on separate lines?

Comment: they are on seperate lines, thanks placing them on same line removes the br tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shortcodes are being placed on separate lines (as confirmed in a comment) within content that is being run through some formatting filters.

One of the filters that is applied to content is known as `wpautop()`. Its purpose is to wrap content within paragraph tags. It'll recognise two line breaks as a new paragraph. It also replaces single line breaks with `<br />` tags, hence your problem.

The simplest solution would be to remove your line breaks. Place the shortcodes directly next to one another to avoid the unwanted break tags being added.

There are more complex options such as conditionally removing the wpautop filter and restoring it with its second argument, `$br`, set to false.